# Root password needed

Tags: password, root

When I first installed Ubuntu 13.04 from a USB stick I was asked to fill in for user username and password so I set one on my own. When I run Ubuntu I click log in but it automatically logs me in as user so I can't type my username. As a result, in order to run certain apps or set up my network I'm asked to type the root password for authentication. I don't wanna log in as a superuser. Please note that I'm a newbie to Ubuntu.

Comment: Read here please:[RootSudo - Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well I did that and it says operation not permitted. What do I do now? :'(

Comment: Automatically logs you in as what user? Guest? Are you asked for a *root* password or an *administrator* password?

Comment: @Seth Guest yeah. I'm asked for a root password. Without it I can't access anything and take advantageof Ubuntu :/

Comment: @ele Try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and logging into text mode.  Does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, there is a difference between your password and the root password (the password of the account "root").

When you first installed Ubuntu, you specified your username (let's say you chose **Ele**) and your password; this is the password that you would use to log in. Since you have Ubuntu to log in automatically, you won't be asked for this password when booting Ubuntu.

The default installation of Ubuntu makes your user an admin; that is, it makes you able to install and remove applications and all that. The password that is asked when you install/remove components is *usually* **your** password, **Ele**'s password. Take a look at these screenshots:

[image]

- This program is asking you to **Enter *your* password**, so this would be the password of **Ele**, that you used to install Ubuntu, which is the same password you use to log in.
- If you did not set a password when you were installing Ubuntu *(and I think this is where your problem is Ele)*, then you need to set a password for your user. To do so, simply type the following command (commands can be typed in a terminal which you can open by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

  ```
  passwd
  ```

  And enter your new password. *Note: you won't see any stars *** or anything; don't worry, just continue typing.*

Now, let's look at another kind of prompt that could ask you for a password:

[image]

- This program is asking you to **Enter the *administrative* password**, which is the root password, the superuser password, the password of the account "root". This password is **NOT** set by default.
- It is generally **not** advisable to set a root password unless you really need to, because it essentially opens doors to lots of *accidental*, *harmful* tasks. But, if you *really* want to set the root password, you would do this:

  ```
  sudo passwd root
  ```

  It will first ask you to enter *your* password, in order to carry out this command (because you typed `sudo`). Then, it will ask you to specify a new `root` password.

  - If *your* account does not have a password set in the first place, this command will not work, because you are performing a `sudo` command, which will require your password first.
- Note1: if you have set a root password and you want to remove it and go back to how it was, do this command:

  ```
  sudo passwd -dl root
  ```

  It will, again, ask you for *your* password, because you are doing a command that starts with `sudo`. This command **d**eletes the password and **l**ocks the `root` account.
- Note2: you **should rarely** see this second screenshot, the one that's asking for the root password. Usually, you'll be asked to enter your user's password. That is how Ubuntu is set up, so that you don't need to log in as the root (superuser) to perform administrative tasks, you only "borrow" the root privileges by using the command `sudo`.

Comment: That's the way :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sudo passwd
```

Essentially, it makes root do 'passwd' which sets a password for the user who used the command.

Comment: If you are setting your own password, there is no need to do `sudo`. Any user can set their own password by issuing the command `passwd` alone.

Answer (score 0):

## How to change your *root* password

For both of the following, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to launch a Terminal window then:

### Method 1

Type in

```
sudo  passwd
```

### Method 2

Type in

```
sudo su
```

Then to create a new password for su enter:

```
passwd.
```

## Conclusion

Essentially, these commands asks *root* to do the `passwd` command. This sets the *root* password which is the one you type to access root privileges with `su`.

`su` offers the following: In terminal and programmes run from terminal, you have changed from being you@your_computer to root@your_computer.

## Edit

Just looked at the other answers and this appears to be an amalgamation of the two previous ones! My apologies.

Comment: No, `sudo passwd` will change the password of the user that executed that command, not the root password. If you want to set the root password, you would do `sudo passwd root`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I know I changed mine, but I couldn't remember how. :)

Comment: The root password? You probably did `sudo passwd root`; take a look at my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Type the following in the command line:

> sudo su

Then generate new password for root:

> passwd

Comment: ouch ! - a teacher with red stick ?    ;-)