# Authentication Password

Tags: password

I am very new to ubuntu and I just downloaded it and its amazing but when I try to download things or create a new user it asks for an authentication password. I need help I have never made one before and I dont know what it is.

Comment: The authentication password should be the same as the login password. You should have set this password during installation of ubuntu. Welcome to ubuntu!

Comment: The password that you are asked for is the password that you setup for your username when you were installing Ubuntu, the password that you use to log in. Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/306898/52726) answer, it might give you more insight.

Answer (score 0):

This is the concept: the user who installs the system is regarded as system admin. Every time you try to do something to the system you just have to say: "Yes, I am aware that this could be serious" **and** "yes, its me (and not somebody else)".

For these purposes you are asked for **your** own password.