# What is the default root password when was never set at installation time?

Tags: password, root

On a standard desktop installation, I created my administrative and user login.
Further with some applications, the system ask for the root password.

So my question is: **What will be the default password for the root login when I never created it during the installation process?**

Answer (score 20):

By default **root** does not have a password and the root account is locked until you give it a password.

When you installed Ubuntu you were asked to create a user with a password.  If you gave this user a password as requested then this is the password you need.  If not, or you have forgotten it,  then you need to set a password.

Instructions on how to do it are here:
[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/107450)

Once you have an administration password you can use `sudo` to run commands that would otherwise require you to be root and enter your password.

If you want to set a root password see this question
[How to enable root login?](https://askubuntu.com/q/44418/107450)

However, read all the answers carefully first to make sure you want to do this.  It's not recommended and many of the answers explain why.

Comment: Just an addition to Warren's answer: read my answer to this question: [Root password needed](http://askubuntu.com/a/306898/52726) if you're getting prompted for a password from a GUI box (don't pay attention to the actual question, just try to understand the difference between the prompts).

Answer (score 17):

Open terminal and type following command:

```
sudo passwd root
```

then press <kbd>enter</kbd> button. Type in your new 'root password', like '123456' and verify the new password, by entering it again, followed by the <kbd>enter</kbd> button.

Now your new 'root password' is set to '123456'.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked, don't suggest setting a root password without mentioning the implications.

Comment: . . . . and certainly do not use ***123456*** as password ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the system is asking for the root password?. It usually asks for **your password** to request elevation.